# Find .html file in directory and rename it

Tags: php, html, file, rename

I have a PHP script that uploads a **.zip** file to my server and unzips it on the server. This zip file contains images, folders and always one html file with a random name.

What I need is a way to locate the html file (randomname.html) and rename it to index.html.

Since I'm pretty new to PHP - any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `glob()` then `rename()`?

Comment: I have fixed English in the first sentence and bolded ".zip"; this is done by surrounding it by two asterisks.  It is also a good idea to post whatever you have tried so far.  It is much easier for people to fix your code than to write a whole block of code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use scandir() function, it returns an array of files & directories in the directory that you specify. Something like this:

```
$path_to_directory = "/path/to/extracted/archive";

$contents = scandir($path_to_directory);

// check if $contents is a directory and actually has items
if (is_array($contents) && count($contents)) {
  foreach($contents as $item) { // loop through directory contents
    if (substr(strtolower($item), -5) == ".html") { // checking if a file ends with .html
      rename($path_to_directory . "/" . $item, $path_to_directory . "/index.html"); // rename it to index.html
      break; // no need to loop more, job's done
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @hallibus glad to hear that :) please accept the answer, too. thanks :)